# Importing a module outside of Jenkins home directory

Tags: python, jenkins, ubuntu-14.04

I am trying to run a custom Python module located at `'/home/modules/module.py'`

The python script is run by Jenkins and located at `'/home/user_name/scripts/script.py'`

Since Jenkins home directory is '/var/lib/jenkins' how can I import my module?

I have tried adding the following to the python script:

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0,'/home/modules') """also /home/modules/"""

import module
```

but I am still getting the error:

```
ImportError: No module named
```

I am running everything in Ubuntu 14.04 and Python 2.7

**EDIT:**

I changed Jenkins user directory  like this:

```
root@dwh-01:~$ usermod -m -d /home/jenkins jenkins
```

and modified `JENKINS_HOME=/home/jenkins`  in  `/etc/default/jenkins`

I think I can work with this, but now the issue is, if I log into jenkins shell and do:

```
jenkins@dwh-01:/$ cd
bash: cd: jenkins/: No such file or directory
```

Should the behaviour of the `cd` command direct me to `/home/jenkins/` ?
If I repeat the same when in `/home/` It works though.

If I try and start jenkins, it gives me:

- `Starting Jenkins Continuous Integration Server jenkins` 
                                                                                                                                                                                 
  `No directory, logging in with HOME=/`

**EDIT-2:**

User jenkins home dir error fixed, I just made sure the home directory of the user was /home/jenkins using `usermod -d /home/jenkins jenkins`

I'm a step closer to importing the module, but am still having issues going one step outside of the jenkins home directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok finally figured it out.
What I did was change in the `/etc/default/jenkins` file the variable **JENKINS_USER** and **JENKINS_GROUP** to the user i needed to outside of the jenkins user folder (outside of `/var/lib/jenkins`).

This way the scripts ran by Jenkins will be ran as if it was the selected user I specified.

After that, I realized that in Jenkins, even if the working directory is `/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/adjust_data_parser/workspace`, scripts and files can be called from '**/**'

So the trick was:

-Accessing the script outside of the jenkins home directory

-Importing the module from its absolute path.

Answer (score 1):

You should have two options that would allow you to import `module` into your code.

**Option 1**

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/home/modules')
import module
```

**Option 2**

```
import importlib.machinery
importlib.machinery.SourceFileLoader('module', '/home/modules').load_module()
```

If neither of these work, hopefully they will at least point you and others in the right direction.

Comment: I edited my comment, I tried already appending the modules folder where the module is contained without any luck:/

Comment: @johan855 What about the second option?

Comment: I am looking more for a way to do this without additional modules, say for example, changing the home path of Jenkins to a closer path where I can perhaps do something like 'sys.path.append('../modules')

Comment: @johan855 From the looks of the two different examples, you are only importing one module in either case. You can either `import sys` or `import importlib` to trying accessing your code. Does it matter which module you import since you only need one?